# Metadata Upgrade behaviour in Unlocked Packages

Tags: salesforcedx, package, isv, unlocked-package, 2gp-ama

**Do ALL metadata types in Unlocked Packages behave the same when the package is upgraded?**

I mean is every change done locally in the subscriber org overwritten by the new package always or are there special cases?

And where would I find them documented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only documentation I know of that addresses this issue is [this old FAQ](https://sfdc-db-gmail.github.io/unlocked-packages/faq-unlocked-pkgs.html).

> With unlocked packages, the admin has the flexibility to make these changes directly in production. The fact that these components belong to a package won’t restrict the flexibility that the admin has towards making changes. However, the admin has to ensure that the development team is informed of these changes. Once the development team is aware of these changes and incorporate them in the next version of the package, installing future versions of the package won’t undo the changes made by the admin in the production org. However, if the changes made directly in production are not applied to the metadata of the package by the development team, subsequent package upgrades will overwrite the changes made in production.

I don't know of any exceptions, although I haven't tested it out on all types of metadata myself. Presumably, the Unlocked Package will always "win" during an upgrade, absent any documentation to the contrary. To be clear, there is no known documentation on exceptions to the contrary that I have ever seen or found, and this warning from the FAQ seems ominous enough to assume there are no exceptions to the rule.

To be safe, you should assume that all metadata components have the same domineering behavior over production metadata. After all, the design of Unlocked Packages was for a company to migrate absolute chunks of metadata in a way to perfectly replicate an org (as much as practicable, anyways). Having exceptions to the rule seems counterproductive to that goal.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_unlocked_pkg_install_pkg_upgrade.htm) custom objects and fields are marked deprecated but not deleted if they contain data even if they were deleted on the upgraded package. Something similar happens for Apex classes if it is referenced in a Lightning component.

The relevant documentation snippets are:

> - User-entered data in custom objects and fields are deprecated and not deleted. Admins can export such data if necessary.
> - An object such as an Apex class is deprecated and not deleted if it is referenced in a Lightning component that is part of the package.

Comment: What about packaged perm sets? Will they be overridden?

Comment: Yes, I just did a test and permission set was completely overriden.